# How can i send data from my Xamarin.Forms application to a Web API

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I want to use code which will work in Android and iOS to send data to an Web API.

I am building a mobile application with Xamarin.Forms for iOS, but i want it to support Android as well.

I use the following code to send data to an Web API:

```cs
string url = String.Format(myURL);
WebRequest requestObj = WebRequest.Create(url);
requestObj.Method = "POST";
requestObj.ContentType = "application/json";

int Klok_id = 10;
string Reden = "DIENST";
string InUit = "U";

string data = "{\"Klok_id\":\"" + Klok_id + "\",\"Reden\":\"" + Reden + "\",\"InUit\":\"" + InUit + "\"}";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(requestObj.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(data);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();

    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Problem with this: It will only work on an iOS and will not work on Android because of the following Error: The "ResolveLibraryProjectImports" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'O:\user\VisualStudio2019\Stage\Koen\Testen\Klokkie\Klokkie\Klokkie\Klokkie.Android\obj\Debug\90\lp\0\jl\formsviewgroup.jar'.

What can i do to resolve this error or is there a better way to send data to an Web API

Comment: Where is the error thrown?

Comment: Try to go through this [link](https://xamgirl.com/consuming-a-restful-web-service-in-xamarin-forms-using-refit-part-1/)
It may help. Let me know in case any query!

Comment: Also I highly recommend replacing the WebRequest code with [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8), and the `data = "...` part with a Model that serializes/ deserializes to the correct JSON or at least update it to use verbatim strings and string interpolation

Comment: @MindSwipe The error is thrown when i run the app on Android. When i run the app on iOS it will work perfectly.

Comment: Which line throws the error when you debug?

Comment: @MattEvans it won't go into the code it will give this error when i try to run my project.

Comment: I added more of the error to my question.

Comment: Looks unrelated to the API call. Is O: a mapped / network drive? What happens if you try and reference it on your local drive?

Comment: O: is an drive provided by my company on there network.

Comment: How can i reference this file on my local drive while my project is still on my network drive?

Comment: @MattEvans I moved my project to my laptops drive and it works now.

Comment: @MattEvans Thanks for taking the time answering my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably another process is locking the file 'formsviewgroup.jar' (maybe another programmer debugging or a firewall scan?) and blocks you to use it, is not a code-related issue i think.
As a global advice i suggest you to not keep your source files on a shared network drive.

L-

Comment: I moved my project to my laptops drive and it works now